# Multicast works in IDLE but not stand-alone

Tags: python, windows, sockets, multicast

I have a simple network of two machines connected directly by cable (no switches, routers, or anything else). One of the machines is a radar, which continously multicasts image data. The other machine is a Windows PC, on which I want to receive that data.

For a first test, I have a simple Python script:

```
import socket

MULTICAST_GROUP = '239.0.17.8'
PORT = 6108
LOCAL_IF = '192.168.3.42'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(1.0)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((LOCAL_IF, PORT))
sock.setsockopt(
    socket.IPPROTO_IP, 
    socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, 
    socket.inet_aton(MULTICAST_GROUP) + socket.inet_aton(LOCAL_IF)
    )

while True:
    try:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(64*1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        print 'timeout'
    else:
        print address, len(data)
```

If I run this from IDLE, it works fine. But if I run it stand-alone (from the command prompt, or double-click in Explorer), it doesn't receive any data; it only prints 'timeout' once a second.

I've been looking at Wireshark output to try to find the difference, but I've found none. Same data arrives, same membership request is sent (the membership is sent twice actually; is that normal?).

The datagrams are quite large (29504 bytes); could that be a problem?

What could be the big difference between running the script within or without IDLE? How can I make it always work ?

Comment: I'm not a windows user, but I bet a dollar on firewall configuration.

Comment: It seems you're right. Quite shameful; I thought of that myself but rejected it, thinking that Windows always asks confirmation instead of silently blocking. I'll do further tests tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 0):

As Michele d'Amico suspected, the problem was a mis-configured firewall. Shame on me for not discovering that myself.